# How to read an existing html file in the WebBrowser control in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

How to read an existing html file in the WebBrowser control in WP7?

I have tried:

1. Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("abc.htm");
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
   string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
   Browser.NavigateToString(html);
2. Browser.Navigate(new Uri("abc.htm", UriKind.Relative));
3. var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("abc.htm", UriKind.Relative));
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
   string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
   Browser.NavigateToString(html);

All three are not working. The methods 1 and 3 gives NullReferenceException because the stream returns null, basically it is not reading my html file.

What is the problem here? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you use number 3, make sure your HTML file has its build type set to 'Content'.

Comment: Sorry - Where do i check that ?

Comment: Select the HTML File and look at its properties in Visual Studio (usually in the bottom right hand corner of VS). There's a section that says `Build Action`. Set that to `content`.

Comment: Thanks!. Yeah i see that set to "Content". Still not working :(

Comment: If the stream is `null`, then it's not being found. Are you sure you have the correct directory path? Are the files definitely `htm` and not `html`? I've written a post here with other methods (and there's one in the comments): https://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/loading-a-local-html-file-in-the-webbrowser-control/

Comment: Path and File names are correct.. Don't know why its not finding it ...Yeah i used all the methods in the link.

Comment: That's quite strange, I've never come across that problem with the emulator. Glad you got it sorted anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use option 2 you must first copy the file to isolated storage if it needs to reference any other files as it's not possible to use relative paths (to other docs, images, js, css, etc.) within a document if loaded directly from the XAP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's a sample:

in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MyBrowser" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("abc.html", UriKind.Relative)); 
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream); 
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
        this.MyBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
    }
```

make sure you have the file "abc.html" (check for typo, your sample code is "abc.**htm**") in your project's root folder. Build action as 'Content' and 'copy to output directory' as 'Do not copy'. It should display the page in the browser.

Comment: Hi - This one is not working either..Its giving me NullReferenceException even though path and file name is correct..

Answer (score 0):

For the first and third :
                         set the Build Action Property of the html file to "Resource"
otherwise it will give you NullReferenceException

For the second :
                browser control in WP7 cannot navigate directly to a html file added in the project. To do this the html file must be located in Isolated Storage.
Try that, i hope it'll work.

(Mark answer, if its helpful).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you add the command inside a button like:

```
    private void htmlLoader(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("abc.html", UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        this.MyBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
    }
```